# Want to sort the data in column after 3rd position

Tags: sql-order-by

I have a table named City and I want the output in a way like 
first 2 rows should have values as "Chennai" then after that from the 3rd position it should sort remaining rows in ascending order starting from a-z.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add some sample data from your `CITY` table, and your SQL statement that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have two entries in `City` for Chennai you could do:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN city = 'Chennai' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    city
```